# STM32: Receiving data via USART

Tags: c, uart, stm32, usart

I'm working on STM32 Discovery (F10x family), and I'm trying to send and receive data through USART1.

```
int uart_putc(int c, USART_TypeDef* USARTx)
{
    assert_param(IS_USART_123_PERIPH(USARTx));

    while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USARTx, USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
    USARTx->DR =  (c & 0xff);
    return 0;
}

int uart_getc (USART_TypeDef* USARTx)
{
    assert_param(IS_USART_123_PERIPH(USARTx));

    while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USARTx, USART_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
    return  USARTx->DR & 0xff;
}
```

`uart_putc` works finely but uart_getc gets stucked in the while loop, it seems like the while condition is never true.
Does someone know what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the STM32 standard peripheral library?

Answer (score 4):

The USART_FLAG_RXNE flag stands for RX buffer Not Empty. If there's data in the RX buffer the flag is SET and not RESET.

That's why your code is stucked in the while loop.

Comment: The only reason `while(a==FALSE)` would be an infinite loop....is because a=FALSE. Isn't that all you're saying here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no problem with your while loop.
By the way you have written the while, it will be executed until RXNE flag becomes SET, right? And that (RXNE == 1) means , there is something in your RX buffer. So when this happens the while loop would no longer be executed.

In my idea the problem problem could be overrun error flag, i mean when you do not read RX buffer and that erase RXNE flag until new data is to be received, Then the overrun error flag become set instead of RXNE flag. and in this case you need to clear ORE flag in order to get back to normal receiving mode, you can do this via `LL_USART_ClearFlag_ORE(USARTx)` if you are using HAL library.
But to make sure that this is the cause of infinite while loop, you can add this condition to the while : `LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_ORE(USARTx)` and it would be like this :

```
while (!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(USART1) && !LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_ORE(USART1))
```

notice that this while is the same as

```
while (LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(USART1) == 0 && LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_ORE(USART1) == 0)
```

That you have already been using.

If this is your issue then there is some methods to improve your algorithm of receiving data:
First one is to use interrupts for receiving data.
Second one is to force compiler to keep your variables in registers for faster execution by using volatile key word before parameters and variables in the function.
And finally i think that by setting your core clock frequency faster enough that your UART working frequency and baud rate might help you to reduce override errors.

Comment: Please format your answer with code tags and proper spelling. It is quite hard to read now

Comment: I have edited my post recently and i think that i have suggested some methods to found out the problem that are based on my experience, I think they are correct, if anybody that down voted this post, thinks it is wrong please share it here, because down voting without telling the reason could be misleading for someone searching for problem solution and right answer.